# Can I do profiles of an Oracle RDS instance on Amazon?

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds

Is there any way to get histories of queries from a 3rd party application to an RDS Oracle instance?

We have a DB with less than a million rows,  and we are running some queries through a 3rd party software.  It's taking over 30 seconds to complete,  which is ridiculous for an Oracle instance with a relatively small data set. Now this software also does some calculations,  so it may be that too, we just don't know.

So we would like to see what queries are being sent in, are the joins done right, are they doing full table scans, etc...

Any tips or software that can help us understand what's taking so long?

Comment: Toad looks to be able to trace on RDS and comes with spotlight on oracle. https://www.quest.com/products/toad-for-oracle/

Comment: tbh, it might not be the individual queries being slow. Think round-trip latency to the RDS instance etc. The Cloud isn't always the silver s̶n̶o̶w̶f̶l̶a̶k̶e̶ bullet that everyone dreams of - it can have huge disadvantages. But, 30 seconds? Even 30 separate queries taking 30 seconds isn't that bad if you add on query parse overhead. Time is money, I wouldn't waste my time investigating

Comment: If you are running the entire product in aws latency on the network isn’t going to be the issue unless you are running the smallest instances possible for RDS and ec2. Even then that might only be a problem if you are returning a million rows as that transfer will take time. If the return has a few hundred rows then you are looking at the right things imo

Comment: @Aaron,  Yes, the entire product is on the same aws network. And both instances are some form of large instance. And if you know of software that does not cost $5k

Comment: Not really a tool but it’s from Oracle and might offer some assistance. But being on RDS you might run into issues if a configuration change is needed and it’s not a listed option.   Also check in the RDS dashboard for that cluster/instance, if they have tracing turned on by default they might expose the latest file that was written for download. https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/manageability/owp-sql-monitoring-128746.pdf